# How to create a neural network that receive multiple input images in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a neural network that receive multiple input images (imageInputLayer)

For example a Siamese architecture for computing the disparity (stereo correspondence) out of two image patches.  The network input is two images and the output is a scalar that represent the disparity.

Currently matlab supports a single imageInputLayer for each neural network. 
I'd like to to classify a 3D object by projecting the 3D object through 3 angles, Therefor converting the problem to classification of 3 images.

I'm trying to create a network that looks like the attached image. 
Please let me know what you think and how to work things out with the network input

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible in Matlab 2018B